# Error in my Constructor?

Tags: java, swing

I have an error to line 42 (new Chanteur ...)
constructor Chanteur in class Chanteur cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,String,String,String,Date
  found: int,String

### reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

(Alt-Enter shows hints)

```
public ArrayList <Album> selectAlbums ()
    {
        ArrayList <Album> myList = new ArrayList();

        String req = "SELECT album.CodeA,album.TitreA,chanteur.IdentC,album.SortieA AS IdentC, chanteur.NomC FROM album INNER JOIN chanteur ON (album.IdentC=chanteur.IdentC) ORDER BY CodeA ASC ";

        ResultSet resu = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().selectQuery (req);

        try {
            while (resu.next())
            {
                myList.add (new Album(resu.getString("CodeA"), resu.getString("TitreA"), 
                             new Chanteur (resu.getInt("IdentC"),resu.getString("NomC")), 
                                  resu.getDate("SortieA")));


            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAOAlbumsMySQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return myList;
    }
```

Visibly, my problem is in my Class Chanteur with the constructor?
I don't see the problem? I don't understand why my code is down...

Comment: The error message seems quite clear: You need to provide 5 arguments (`int,String,String,String,Date` - "identC, nomC, prenomC, sexeC, NaissC"), but you are only providing 2 (`int,String` - "IdentC, NomC").

Comment: @Marvin; thank you my problem is resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Chanteur`'s constructor expects:

```
int identC, String nomC, String prenomC, String sexeC, Date NaissC
```

While the parameters passed to the constructor are:

```
resu.getInt("IdentC"), resu.getString("NomC")), resu.getDate("SortieA"))
```

It just does not match.

You can create a new constructor which accepts `int, String, Date`:

```
public Chanteur(int identC, String nomC, Date NaissC) {
    this.identC = identC;
    this.nomC = nomC;
    this.NaissC = NaissC;
}
```

or you need pass the complete parameters to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you are requesting an int, String, String, String and a Date. In your code, you are only supplying an int, a String and a Date.

If you only want to supply 3 arguments, you could create another constructor that only requires 3 arguments. Research Overloading.

Answer (score 0):

constructor overloading is where you provide two or more constructors to the same class but with different arguments this enables your class to decide at runtime which constructor to call according to the values you have passed to it.

for your case consider adding this constructor to your class that is going to overload the current constructor and get called when you execute your code

```
public Chanteur(int identC, String nomC, Date NaissC) {
this.identC = identC;
this.nomC = nomC;
this.NaissC = NaissC;
}
```

Comment: Austine Gwa: mercy  a lot